# Who has defeated Lady Shiva?

Tags: dc

As I recall, it's a very short list

> - Cassandra Cain (twice)
>  - Batman
>  - Tim Drake (with bo)
>  - David Cain

Is there any one else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at the Wikipedia entry for [Lady Shiva](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_Shiva#Shiva_and_Batgirl) are the following who have defeated her not including the ones already listed:

- Cheshire
- Prometheus
- Victor Sage (as a Black Lantern)

Additionally Richard Dragon was in a position to kill her once, but was prevented by Shiva's henchmen. When they resumed combat Shiva was able to get the upper hand.

After reviewing several wikis, including DC-Comics and the Batman wiki (of which all seem to be heavily plagarized from either the main Wikipedia article or elsewhere) I found no additional names. The Batman wiki claims that Batman and Cassandra Cain are the only two beat Shiva in single-handed combat. As everyone else had either weapons, powers, or circumstances that helped them defeat her.

Answer (score 1):

She's been beaten (if not badly) at different points.

Richard Dragon defeated her on several occasions (though to be fair, she has stomped *him* in retaliation at times, too)
[image]

Black Canary didn't *defeat* her on one occasion, but she *did* fight her to a stand still/draw....

[image]

Bronze  Tiger did the same, but I can't find a scan...

And her daughter, Cassandra, aka Batgirl, **finally** managed to do so after numerous battles....

[image]

She did so again post Rebirth

[image]

Batman *also* has defeated Shiva on occasion, though to be fair, she tends to come out on top more often than not. In the instance below, for example, she was being controlled to a degree...

[image]

I know there are a few more, but those are usually under distinct circumstances (she's been drugged, overhwlemed by numbers, fought at a handicap, something like that.)

Generally speaking, though, Shiva is seen as one of **the** most dominant, almost unbeatable fighters in the DC universe.

Comment: Unbeatable, aside from the literally dozens of people who've beaten her?

Comment: @Valorum you must need glasses, as you missed the "almost" there, Breddah. And if there have been "dozens"... WHY are there only 3 or 4 listed beyond the answers I mentioned? This is also why I tried to include panels, so that there is evidence to support the defeats. I know there have been wins for Bronze Tiger, Death Stroke, I _think_ Wonder Woman, Huntress and O-Sensei at some points... but I can't find them, personally. Just wanted to highlight the few I knew specifically.

Comment: Well, multiple people on a dozen occasions. And I doubt that every fight she's ever been in has been shown in the comics :-)

Comment: @Valorum That, I can agree on. I know Richard and Bruce have beaten her multiple times, but only so many fights are highlighted. Besides, she, like Bruce, has had likely hundreds, if not _thousands_ of battles outside of the major foes; we're talking grunts, goons, goombas, hired thugs, bodyguards, assassins and challengers.